# How can I set the window text of an application using .NET Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Previously, I've used a `.bat` file to run some console application .exe's. When I do this, I can set the process windows title text.

for example:-

`START "1 - 203.46.105.23:20600 - Sydney 24/7 #1" "C:\MyApplication\Streams\PBUcon\pbucon.exe" ini="C:\MyApplication\Streams\Active\1-203.46.105.23.20600.ini"`

So this executes the file pbucon.exe and passes in some argument to the exe. The console window title is `1 - 203.46.105.23:20600 - Sydney 24/7 #1`

[image]

I'm not sure how i can do this programatically using the Process command?

here's what I'm doing ...

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        Arguments = string.Format("ini={0}", GameServerFile(gameServer, false)),
        FileName = newPbUconFile,
        WorkingDirectory = ActiveFolder
    };

Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Is it possible?

For what it's worth, I'm also running a console app which kicks off those pbucon.exe's (when required)... and does lots of other stuff.

Comment: You can call a batch file from C#...

Comment: I know - but i was curious to see if can do it without that.

Comment: There is nothing in the `Process` / `ProcessStartInfo` classes that will let you do that, so I suspect you would have to p/Invoke to achieve this.

Comment: any clues how to do this via p/Invoke?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somwhere in your code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string windowClass, string windowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);

public void startProcess(string path, string title) {
   Process.Start(path);
   Thread.Sleep(1000); //Wait, the new programm must be full loaded
   IntPtr handle = FindWindow("ConsoleWindowClass", path); //get the Handle of the 
                                                           //console window
   SetWindowText(handle, title); //sets the caption
}
```

### Update by Pure Krome

Instead of looking for the handle, the process already has that info... So i did this (because my program i was starting was a console app, if that has anything to do with this ... )

```
..... snipped .....
var process = Process.Start(path);
Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait for the new program to start.
SetWindowText(process.MainWindowHandle, title);
```

HTH.

Comment: You should probably use `Process.WaitForInputIdle()` instead of a sleep. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcdbkyt4.aspx

Comment: @dss `WaitForInputIlde()` [doesn't do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33405201/1889329). The get notified about window creation you could set up a [CBT hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v%3Dvs.85)) or use [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents).

Comment: @dss The Windows API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-waitforinputidle) is generally more accurate than the .NET framework's.