# CloseWindow doesn't minimize window from the process I just launched

Tags: c++, winapi

Well I want to minimize the window after starting the window but it doesn't take effect and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can you please point out the mistake in the code below?

Nothing happens other than that a window is opened.

```
HWND  g_hwnd;
int  g_nFound;

BOOL CALLBACK FindHwndFromPID(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);

HWND GetHwndFromPID(DWORD dwProcessId)
{
g_hwnd = NULL;
g_nFound = 0;

EnumWindows(FindHwndFromPID, (LPARAM)dwProcessId);

if (g_hwnd)  // we found one...
    return (g_hwnd);

// nothing found :-(

return (NULL);
}

BOOL CALLBACK FindHwndFromPID(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
DWORD   dwPID2Find = (DWORD)lParam;
DWORD   dwPID = 0;

if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID))
{
    if (dwPID == dwPID2Find)
    {
        g_hwnd = hwnd;


        return  (FALSE);
    }
}

return  (TRUE);
}


 int main
 {
     ..../
 if (!CreateProcessA(NULL,     // No module name (use command line)
     command_line.GetBuffer(),
     NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
     NULL,           // Thread handle not inhberitable
     FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
     0,              // No creation flags
     NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
     NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
     &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
     &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
     )
 {

     //... error handling
     return 0;
 }

 WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, 1000);
 HWND hwnds = GetHwndFromPID(pi.dwProcessId);

 printf("Process Handle %d, hwnd id: %p ",pi.dwProcessId, hwnds);

 CloseWindow(hwnds);
```

That code is supposed to minimize the window but I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: I don't see any call to MinimizeWindow.  (I see a call to CloseWindow - but that should just close it, minimize).  You will have to debug your GetHwndFromPID.

Comment: @Martin Bonner Yes CloseWindow doesn't even do anything............. printf("Process Handle %d, hwnd id: %p ",pi.dwProcessId, hwnds); prints hwid id.

Comment: @MegRay Are you sure you've retrieved a correct window handle? Try checking the handle value using "Spy++" tool. Also, you are not checking the output from `WaitForInputIdle`, maybe a timeout occurs ...

Comment: @Marko Popovic if (!CloseWindow(hwnds))
  {
   printf("CloseWindow failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
   getchar();
  }

No error found too

Comment: @Marko Popovic I see handle ID is different so the problem occurs in Getting Handle ID from process id.

Comment: @MegRay OK, fix that and then see if it works correctly.

Comment: WaitForInputIdle [doesn't do, what you think it does](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33405201/1889329).

Comment: @MartinBonner there is no `MinimizeWindow()`, and [`CloseWindow()` minimizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (It gets weirder, instead of `UnminimizeWindow()` or `RestoreWindow()` it's [`OpenIcon()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).) I'm guessing the modern way for both is to use `ShowWindow()`, but I wouldn't know for sure. (This probably wouldn't solve the OP's issue; I don't know what the solution is, and IInspectable probably has it anyway.)

Comment: @MegRay: is there a reason why you are trying to use `CloseWindow()` at all, instead of using the **official** method of requesting the spawned app to run minimized? Pass a `STARTUPINFO` struct to `CreateProcess()`, where the `dwFlags` is set to `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` and the `wShowWindow` is set to `SW_MINIMIZE`, `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`, or `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE` as needed. The `wShowWindow` value will take effect the first time the spawned process calls `ShowWindow()` for itself. This is documented behavior.

Comment: you got `STARTUP_INFO`, why don't use it (`STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW + SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`)

Comment: @milevyo 9 my question why doesn't my hwnd id doesn't works correctly.
I have the or i get id but it seems to be wrong.

Comment: What if the program creates multiple windows? Most programs create a bunch of helper windows in addition to the main window. Your program just grabs the first window, which might be a tooltip or some other helper window.

Comment: Agreed.  I would suggest using Spy++ to look at the actual class name and/or window title of the specific window you are interested in, and then code your enumeration to look for those values using `GetClassName()` and `GetWindowText()`.  Or, if the values are fixed, not dynamic, you could just skip `EnumWindows()` and use `FindWindow/Ex()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well the window am trying to get is google chrome window. i found that the hwnd id retuned is some black box but not the window that opened.

Comment: @MegRay: Like Raymond said, that is perfectly acceptable. You can't just grab the first `HWND` you find, there may be others available. You have to analyze each one and then act accordingly.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Can you give me any kind of solution?

Comment: @MegRay: I already did. Read my previous comments again more carefully, in particular the one that agrees with Raymond Chen's comment. I told you what you will have to do to find the window.  It also looks like milevyo has also posted an answer that shows how to enumerate widows when dealing with processes that create their own child processes (we don't know if that is what is happening in your case, as you have not provided any information about the app you are launching from your code).

Comment: Note that all of this is very fragile. Any future change to Chrome may invalidate your code. Better would be to look for an officially supported interface for launching Chrome and controlling its lifetime.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Well i used EnumWindows() and GetWindowTextA to work it out.

Answer (score 4):

You are going about this the wrong way.  The **official and documented** way to ask a spawned process to run initially minimized is to use the `STARTUPINFO` structure when calling `CreateProcess()`, eg:

```
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE;

    //...

    if (!CreateProcessA(..., &si, ...))
    {
        //... error handling
        return 0;
    }

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

[STARTUPINFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331.aspx)

> wShowWindow
>   If dwFlags specifies STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, this member can be any of the values that can be specified in the nCmdShow parameter for the ShowWindow function, except for SW_SHOWDEFAULT. Otherwise, this member is ignored.
>
> **For GUI processes, the first time ShowWindow is called, its nCmdShow parameter is ignored wShowWindow specifies the default value. In subsequent calls to ShowWindow, the wShowWindow member is used if the nCmdShow parameter of ShowWindow is set to SW_SHOWDEFAULT.**

[ShowWindow function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx)

> nCmdShow [in]
>   Type: int
>
> Controls how the window is to be shown. **This parameter is ignored the first time an application calls ShowWindow, if the program that launched the application provides a STARTUPINFO structure**. Otherwise, the first time ShowWindow is called, the value should be the value obtained by the WinMain function in its nCmdShow parameter.
>
> ...
>
> The first time an application calls ShowWindow, it should use the WinMain function's nCmdShow parameter as its nCmdShow parameter. Subsequent calls to ShowWindow must use one of the values in the given list, instead of the one specified by the WinMain function's nCmdShow parameter.
>
> As noted in the discussion of the nCmdShow parameter, **the nCmdShow value is ignored in the first call to ShowWindow if the program that launched the application specifies startup information in the structure. In this case, ShowWindow uses the information specified in the STARTUPINFO structure to show the window**. On subsequent calls, the application must call ShowWindow with nCmdShow set to SW_SHOWDEFAULT to use the startup information provided by the program that launched the application. This behavior is designed for the following situations:
>
> • Applications create their main window by calling CreateWindow with the WS_VISIBLE flag set.
>
> • Applications create their main window by calling CreateWindow with the WS_VISIBLE flag cleared, and later call ShowWindow with the SW_SHOW flag set to make it visible.

Comment: Well the HWND is necessary for me to do any activity like destroying the window after the usage and that is the exactly what i want. The question a bit misleading i think. Sorry, Please tell me how do i work out for HWND ID.

Comment: @MegRay: Or, you could just post a `WM_QUIT` message to the spawned process's main thread ID instead of any particular `HWND`.  Or, you could just `TerminateProcess()` the spawned process if you are that determined to kill it programmably instead of letting it exit itself gracefully. In any case, you already know how to find the `HWND`, there is nothing wrong with that code you showed.  So either you are searching for the `HWND` before it has been created, or maybe the `HWND` you are finding is not the same `HWND` that the app displays to the user. Like Marco said, use Spy++ to verify.

Comment: Well i already used spy++ and i see it showing entirely different Process ID and HWND ID I prinited for debug purpose.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your `HWND` enumeration (though you are not doing error handling on `EnumWindows()`, and `g_nFound` is not being used). Unless the `HWND` is being created after `WaitForInputIdle()` has exited, you will just have to debug your code and see what is really happening. Given the code you have shown, it is not possible for the enumeration to return a non-zero `HWND` that does not belong to the process ID that `CreateProcess()` reports. So either you are printing it out wrong, or you are misinterpreting what Spy++ is showing you.

Comment: Note  For Windows 8 and later, EnumWindows enumerates only top-level windows of desktop apps. I see this note on EnumWindows function. Does this effect this in any way?

Comment: @MegRay: It is differentiating between Desktop apps and Universal apps. And no, it does not really affect the outcome in this case. If your enumeration ends up with a non-zero `HWND`, it would still match the process ID of the app you spawned, due to `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`. If you spawned a Universal app, you would end up with a zero `HWND` if `EnumWindows()` skips its windows. But `CreateProcess()` is not the right way to launch a Universal app to begin with, so this is really a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

because the application window may not belong to the started process, but instead it belongs to its child process, you have to go deeper in `FindHwndFromPID` by including the parent process in the comparison.

also we shall not count on `WaitForInputIdle()` by it self, you have to give the created process enough time to fully initialize.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

HWND  g_hwnd;
int  g_nFound;

BOOL CALLBACK FindHwndFromPID(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);
/*___________________________________________________________________________________________________
*/
HWND GetHwndFromPID(DWORD dwProcessId)
{
    g_hwnd = NULL;
    g_nFound = 0;

    EnumWindows(FindHwndFromPID, (LPARAM)dwProcessId);

    if (g_hwnd)  // we found one...
        return (g_hwnd);

    // nothing found :-(

    return (NULL);
}
/*___________________________________________________________________________________________________
*/
DWORD GetParentProcess(DWORD pid){
    PROCESSENTRY32 p32={sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)};
    DWORD ParentPID=0;
    HANDLE hSnapShot =  CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    if(Process32First(hSnapShot,&p32)){
        do{
            if(p32.th32ProcessID==pid){
                ParentPID = p32.th32ParentProcessID;
                break;
            }
        }while(Process32Next(hSnapShot,&p32));
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot);

    return ParentPID;

}
/*___________________________________________________________________________________________________
*/
int __stdcall WindowText(HWND hWnd,LPSTR lpString,int nMaxCount){
    int ret;
    ret=SendMessage(hWnd,WM_GETTEXTLENGTH,0,0);
    if(ret){
        ret=SendMessage(hWnd,WM_GETTEXT,nMaxCount,(LPARAM)lpString);
    }
    return ret;
}
/*___________________________________________________________________________________________________
*/
BOOL CALLBACK FindHwndFromPID(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam){
    DWORD   dwPID2Find = (DWORD)lParam;
    DWORD   dwPID = 0;

    if(GetWindowLong(hwnd,GWLP_HWNDPARENT) || !IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
        return 1;

    if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID)){
        if ((dwPID == dwPID2Find) || ( GetParentProcess(dwPID) == dwPID2Find)){
            g_hwnd = hwnd;
            return  (FALSE);
        }
    }

    return  (TRUE);
}
/*___________________________________________________________________________________________________
*/

int main(){
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si={sizeof(si)};
    TCHAR exename[]=TEXT("write.exe"); // writable buffer (for Unicode bug.)
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,exename,NULL,    NULL,FALSE, 0,     NULL,NULL,&si,     &pi)){
        return 0;
    }


   //WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, 1000); // this alown will not always work (process may have children)

   // give enough time to process to fully initialize
   // put all in a loop until you
   // get the window handle or timeout.

HWND hwnds = GetHwndFromPID(pi.dwProcessId);
for( int i=0 ;i<1000;i++ ){
    if(hwnds)
        break;
    Sleep(10); 
    hwnds = GetHwndFromPID(pi.dwProcessId);
}

    printf("Process Handle %d, hwnd id: %p ",pi.dwProcessId, hwnds);

    CloseWindow(hwnds);


    return 0;
}
```