# WaitforInputIdle doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

I am trying to launch a process from my WPF application.The process is also a WPF application developed using PRISM/MEF framework.

```
 var process = Process.Start(processPath);
 process.WaitForInputIdle();
 Console.WriteLine(process.MainWindowHandle);

 //rest of the code
```

The problem is with PRISM/MEF application as process WaitForInputIdle() doesn't work.I tried printing mainwindowHandle and its zero after WaitForInputIdle().

Whereas I tried opening other process like notepad.exe ,WaitForInputIdle() works and prints the window handle.

Now I am using this workaround ,but can anyone tell why WaitForInputIdle() is not working properly?

```
 var process = Process.Start(processPath);
 process.WaitForInputIdle();
 Console.WriteLine(process.MainWindowHandle)

 while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
       {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
       }
 //rest of the code
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WaitForInputIdle doesn't work for starting mspaint programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405201/waitforinputidle-doesnt-work-for-starting-mspaint-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

The [**`Process.WaitForInputIdle()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2(v=vs.110).aspx) just waits for the process's message loop to enter an idle state. Like your loop `WaitForInputIdle()` is also a workaround, it is not specifically coded to wait for the `MainWindowHandle` to be created. So depending on how the application works there's no guarantee that the window handle has been created by the time the method returns.

At least most of Windows's built-in apps uses the same methods as the Windows Forms applications for starting the app and creating the first window. In those cases the standard behaviour *is* that the process will enter an idle state when the window handle is created and the window is shown.

WPF, Prism and MEF works a bit differently than WinForms, thus there's no guarantee that the window handle has been created when the application finally enters an idle state. Unfortunately I'm not very much into WPF nor Prism or MEF, so I cannot even provide a theory about this behaviour.

Comment: Note that, in particular, if a process hits some sort of COM wait and starts processing messages, Windows will treat this as if it's reached "input idle". At least, that's one of the most common scenarios where this happens. WPF does not actually work very much differently from Winforms; I would not expect to see a WPF program reach input idle before its main window has been created, except when the same program implemented as Winforms would as well. I.e. both would be calling something else that tricked Windows; it's not something the usual API template would cause.

Comment: @PeterDuniho : Thanks for your comment. As I mentioned I'm not very familiar with how WPF/Prism/MEF works, so I don't really know how it creates its windows and what it does in its message loop.

Comment: You are missing the important details: `WaitForInputIdle` waits at most once per process, and returns as soon as a thread is ready to process messages (**any** thread). Depending on your specific setup, the system will create (or inject) threads into every process, so any process may have threads that are ready to process messages at any point, irrespective of the platform or framework used. `WaitForInputIdle` was invented for DDE. Using it for anything else is a bug (and using DDE is - arguably - a bug, too).

Comment: @IInspectable : I was not aware of that. However the specific thread doesn't really matter since once there's a message loop there's most likely a window too. -- Why was it invented only for DDE? I've never heard of that before.

Comment: [DDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange) relies on a message-based protocol, so it runs a message loop **without** any GUI. It was mostly superseded by OLE. Irrespective of that, there are many implementations based on messages without a GUI. [Message-only windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only) were specifically invented for this. And then there are the more common failure modes, e.g. an application displaying a splash screen. At any rate, `WaitForInputIdle` is usually not a solution to any problem.

Comment: @IInspectable : [**According to the MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2(v=vs.110).aspx) it would be.

Comment: As explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33410894/1889329), the documentation is inaccurate. Besides, like the MFC documentation, the .NET documentation is below standard of the Windows API documentation (see [WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022.aspx)).

Comment: @IInspectable : Interesting points. And not that I don't believe you, but even the WinAPI documentation mentions it: _"For example, the parent process should use the WaitForInputIdle function before trying to find a window associated with the child process."_

Comment: As I said, the MSDN isn't very accurate here. It is true, that a window requires a message queue, and `WaitForInputIdle` could be used as a tiny optimization. But that's not what it's for. If you want to be notified about window creation, use the right tool (e.g. [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx)).