# C++ - Launch Notepad from an MFC application and change its default title from "Untitled - Notepad" to something else

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am using the following piece of code on Windows to successfully open an instance of Notepad. How can I change its default title from "Untitled - Notepad" to something else?

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = { 0 };

sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
sei.hwnd = my_hWnd; // this window's handle
sei.lpVerb = L"open";
sei.lpFile = L"notepad.exe";
sei.lpParameters = NULL;
sei.lpDirectory = NULL;
sei.nShow = SW_SHOW;
sei.hInstApp = NULL;

if (ShellExecuteEx(&sei))
{
    // do some other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `ShellExecuteEx()` for this? You are not opening a document, you are starting a process, so you should be using `CreateProcess()` instead. `ShellExecuteEx()` is just going to start a new process anyway, so cut out the middleman.

Comment: You can't. The window title is managed by the application, and you don't know, how it does that. [The secret life of GetWindowText](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833) explains, how windows can manage their window titles.

Answer (score 0):

There is limited set of command line options in Notepad.exe to change the default filename. But you can specify the new filename like so, if it doesn't exist, a prompt will let you open it as a new document.

```
sei.lpFile = L"notepad.exe";
sei.lpParameters = L"\"Readme.txt\"";
```

Comment: This solution isn't bad but I wanted Notepad to open without displaying the prompt. Thumbs up!

Comment: Yeah, sure, this does answer the question *"How can I change its default title \[...\] to something else?"*, provided that *"something else"* is still supposed to end in *" - Notepad"*. It doesn't provide a general solution. @mel: What prompt?

Comment: @IInspectable If you do specify a filename for a file that doesn't exist, Notepad will prompt you to create it. I'd rather it didn't but that's probably its default behavior and is unavoidable. I even tried SetWindowText() which worked for a split second (observed this in the debugger) and then Notepad reset it.

Comment: To avoid that prompt, simply create an empty file and pass its name. However, it is still not clear what OP wanted to see in the changed title...

Comment: @VladFeinstein I prefer not to create a file on disk. In hindsight, I should have mentioned this in the main post but I wasn't sure as to how much detail I needed to include.

Comment: @melanie93 - I think this question came up a couple of times already: WHAT exactly do you wan to see in the title?

Comment: The title should be a string of my choice but I don't think that's possible unless I create the file on disk. Using SetWindowText() works temporarily and then Notepad resets the title. Shall I close this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateProcess()` to create the Notepad process.

Use `WaitForInputIdle()` to wait until the window becomes available. (Note: this approach may not work reliably, follow [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410894/1889329) to implement the WinEvents approach).

Use `EnumThreadWindows()` on the main thread ID (obtained from `PROCESS_INFORMATION`) to get the Notepad window handle.

Finally, use `SendMessage()` with `WM_SETTEXT` on the window handle to change the window title to whatever you like.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumThreadWndProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND hWndNp = hWnd; 
    SendMessageW(hWndNp, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (WPARAM)L"Hello");
    return 0; // ...stop enum
}

int main() {

    STARTUPINFOW si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (!CreateProcessW(
        NULL, _tcsdup(TEXT("notepad")),
        NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL,           
        &si, &pi)           
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    if (0 == WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, 5000))
    {
        EnumThreadWindows(pi.dwThreadId,
            EnumThreadWndProc, NULL);
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [WaitForInputIdle doesn't do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410894/1889329).

Comment: Ah, OK. Always worked for me, but I guess the documentation is misleading. I'll let the OP implement the WinEvents (or hooks) approach as recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
CString strFile("C:\\test.txt");
char sz[MAX_PATH];
wsprintf(sz, "Notepad.exe %s", strFile);
WinExec(sz, SW_SHOW);
```

Also you can set default file name or path.