# Control the application using C# application

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

i want to clicked the save button of another application from my c# application.if there is data in that application then save dialogbox will appear while in absence of data message box will appear.After i want to give the filename as date and time similarly i want to click the ok button for messagebox.

i did it using 3 button save,enter filename button and ok button but the problem is when i clicked the save button window is changed to either save dialogbox or message box after that my c# application freezed. if i restart c# application it will work.how to solve this?
if possible i want to do it using single button.

````
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]static public extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rectangle lpRect);
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
 private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
 private static extern int SendNotifyMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
 [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr points);
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
 //save button
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    IntPtr maindHwnd = FindWindow(null, "app1");
    IntPtr maindHwnd1 = FindWindow(null, "Error");
    if (maindHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
     IntPtr panel = FindWindowEx(maindHwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "MDIClient", null);
     IntPtr panel1 = FindWindowEx(panel, IntPtr.Zero, "TAveForm", null);
     IntPtr panel2 = FindWindowEx(panel1, IntPtr.Zero, "TPanel", "Panel5");
     IntPtr panel3 = FindWindowEx(panel2, IntPtr.Zero, "TPanel", null);
     IntPtr childHwnd = FindWindowEx(panel3, IntPtr.Zero, "TBitBtn", "Save");
  if (childHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
     {
      SendMessage(childHwnd, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
     }
   }
  }
//click messagebox
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Error");
    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
      IntPtr childHwnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Ok"); 
     if (childHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
      {
        SendMessage(childHwnd, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); 
        }
      else
      {
        textBox3.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        textBox3.Text = "error;
                }
         }
         else
         {
          textBox3.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        textBox3.Text = "hmd is zero";
         }
        }
 //save dialogbox
String textBox = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HH-mm-ss");
  IntPtr maindHwnd = FindWindow(null, "save");
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Error");
   if (maindHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
   {
     IntPtr panel = FindWindowEx(maindHwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBoxEx32", null);
      IntPtr panel1 = FindWindowEx(panel, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBox", null);
      IntPtr panel2 = FindWindowEx(panel1, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
       if (panel2 != IntPtr.Zero)
        {

          SendKeys.Send(textBox);
                       
         }

                } ```
````

Comment: UI Automation is a better technology for interacting with apps from an external application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview

Answer (score -2):

IMHO the easiest way is to first, find out the target application Window Handle and target application's process ID.

Then you can interrupt with it's child objects.

Example:

```
public static void chooseMode(IntPtr hnd, int PID)
        {
            if (hnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var proc = Process.GetProcessById(PID);
                proc.WaitForInputIdle();
                SetForegroundWindow(hnd);
                SendKeys.SendWait(@"%V {UP 3} ~");
            }
        }
```

Comment: That assumes that [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) cannot fail, which it can, and usually will. Also, `WaitForInputIdle` [doesn't do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410894/1889329).